# Paste & set color with a single button (for palettes)

Tags: front-end, palettes

I need to use some colors frequently so I decided to make a palette for this. This is an example palette button that inserts a color:

```
CreatePalette[PasteButton[RGBColor[.5, .6, .7], RGBColor[.5, .6, .7]]]
```

But I may also want to set some text inside a non input cell to that color. So for that this works:

```
CreatePalette[
  Button[RGBColor[.5, .6, .7], 
    FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[
                       SelectedNotebook[],
                       FontColor, 
                       RGBColor[.5, .6, .7]]}]]]
```

or

```
CreatePalette[
  Button[RGBColor[.5, .6, .7], 
    CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], FontColor] = RGBColor[.5, .6, .7]]]
```

But I don't want two create two buttons for each color. I prefer to have a single button that inserts a color if nothing is selected (1st case) or styles some text is there is a selection.

This is what I have tried to do (but it does not work):

```
CreatePalette[
  Button[RGBColor[.5, .6, .7],
    If[CurrentValue["SelectionData"] == $Failed,
       NotebookWrite[ButtonNotebook[], RGBColor[.5, .6, .7]],
       FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], FontColor, RGBColor[.5, .6, .7]]}]]]]
```

Can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
CreatePalette[Button["Crazy Color Palette",
  ib := InputNotebook[];
  If[NotebookRead[ib] === {},
     NotebookWrite[ib, "RGBColor[.5,.6,.7]"], 
     FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[ib, FontColor, RGBColor[.5, .6, .7]]}]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it does not solve the problem. Try your palette in a single word in a text cell and it gets replaced by RGBColor[.5,.6,.7] insteas of being styled in that color.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Try it now, please

Comment: Yes! It now works. I now see that you used SetDelayed inside the palette. Nice!